# How to fix error :processDebugMainManifest DEBUG

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, mobile

I faced this debug while trying to run my own flutter project in device.this is some description::
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @6109445c

- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Can anyone could help me!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error :processDebugMainManifest DEBUG in flutter while run from android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69985172/how-to-fix-error-processdebugmainmanifest-debug-in-flutter-while-run-from-andro)

Answer (score 5):

I just experienced this myself [while checking java16 compatibility with Ankidroid (link because it is open source, you can reproduce yourself if you like)](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/pull/8634).

I would guess you are attempting to use java16 to compile your app?

As of this writing (April 16, 2021) Android Gradle Plugin is not compatible with java16 - not 4.1.3, 4.2.0-rc01 nor 7.0.0alpha14 (all the current versions as I write this.

If you use java8 or java11 it works.

Android Studio uses java11 internally now for 4.2.x so that is the safest bet at this point for Android development.

I have logged this upstream issue so Google is aware, and others may track it in case there is a good workaround/explanation/reason https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/186806275

Comment: Uninstalled 16 and installed 11. It started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved same issue with following commands

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre

ln -s ../jre jdk

ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk

flutter doctor -v
```

Clean and run it will work.

Comment: Basically these above command according to Mac so if you are using Windows or Linux please change path accordingly.