# How to properly release a flutter application

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

I am new to the flutter framework, and tried the default code in my browser and my physical device using adb, which worked fine, but when I tried to get the apk file, I got an error which I cannot solve. I have followed the Official Docs for Build And Release. Here is the log:

```
E:\Android Applications\myapp>flutter build apk --release

 Building with sound null safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessib
le: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @70cb5dd9



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            7.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Please Help Me Fix this Error. Note: I do have JDK and JRE installed, Working Properly and added to the path. I have configured the `build.gradle` file as well.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66825342/how-to-fix-error-processdebugmainmanifest-debug ?

Comment: No it's not the same