# Flutter :app:processDebugMainManifest error when running app

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm developong a flutter mobile application but whenever I try to run it, it throws the following :app:processDebugMainManifest error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @7ea904ce
```

When I run flutter doctor the only issue is android studio not being installed (despite being installed).

Comment: Check for that answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66825342/how-to-fix-error-processdebugmainmanifest-debug where might be the issue with the java version you are trying to use.