# How to fix error :processDebugMainManifest DEBUG in flutter while run from android studio

Tags: android, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @fb04536

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: this is due to jdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved same issue with following commands

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre

ln -s ../jre jdk

ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
```

Run and check.