# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'. in ReactNative CLI

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-cli

I try to build a ReactNative app using ReactNative CLI following the steps in their documentation: [Link for the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

After downloading the initializing the App I tried to run the app:

1. `npx react-native start` - to start the metro bundler and it's successfully launched.
2. `npx react-native run-android` - to start the application on the android emulator but failed to build.

It gave the following error message:

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
> development environment set up:
> https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Error: Command failed:
> gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 Warning:
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02
> to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns
> http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns
> http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01 Warning:
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02
> to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns
> http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns
> http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01 Warning:
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02
> to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
>
> > Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens
> > java.io" to unnamed module @26c4a53

The problem is I have already added the required path variables as follows. So, how can I get the above error? Does anybody know how to resolve this issue, please?

**Screenshot of the powershell output for checking 'User variables':**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error :processDebugMainManifest DEBUG in flutter while run from android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69985172/how-to-fix-error-processdebugmainmanifest-debug-in-flutter-while-run-from-andro)

Comment: @Thanhal It does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is associated with the JDK version. There are many solutions I came across in different platforms which relate to the Android SDK and emulator but non solved the issue.
Finally, I carried out the following steps and the issue was solved.

1. **If you have already installed the JDK 17 or any other version, uninstall it.**
2. **Then download and install the JDK version 8**
   Refer to the link: [Download from here](http://C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CCommon%20Files%5COracle%5CJava%5Cjavapath)
3. **Set the environmental variables as follows** 
    
   Advanced system settings -> Environmental Variables -> System variables 
   Next, in the 'System variables' click on 'New' and, add `JAVA_HOME` (if it is not available) as variable name and add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202` as the 'Variable value' and Ok. 
   This path is the directory path where you installed the JDK. Keep in mind to take the path without including the `/bin` folder. 
    
    [image] 
   In the `Path` of 'System variables', click edit and add the following path variables to the **top** of the list and save.

   `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

    
   [image]
4. **Now restart the computer and rerun the application**

Answer (score 2):

This is the main error I had: > Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

I fixed it by adding android:exported="true" to the \android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml files activity section. For example:

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:exported="true"> // <- add it here. ! . !
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and just after cd .\android\ & ./gradlew clean!

Comment: This helped me get past the error as well. I'm not sure if this a new requirement or why its necessary, but it did work.